# Django Signals maximum recursion depth when updating model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to update a status field via signals but get a max recursion error. Using django 4.1.1.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
  # ….
    PRODUCT_STATUS = (
        ('P', _('Preparation')),
        ('S', _('Sold')),
        ('T', _('Shipped')),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True,
                              choices=PRODUCT_STATUS, default='P')
    price_sold = models.DecimalField(
        _('Price Sold'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

#…
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def post_save_product_set_status_sold_if_price_sold(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.price_sold != None:
        instance.status = 'S'
        instance.save(update_fields=['status'])
```

I get the following error when saving

*RecursionError at /admin/products/product/14/change/
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object*

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

it is clear. On after_save Product signal you call save Product and it triggered signal after_save Product and .... recursion.

in your case:

```
def post_save_product_set_status_sold_if_price_sold(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.price_sold != None:
        type(instance).objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(status = 'S')
```

And probably you need `pre-save` signal.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#pre-save

But i don't understand, why you want to do it with signal.
You can:

- check it on `form.clean()` (best)
- check it on `model.full_clean()` (good)
- do it on `form.save()` (normal)
- do it on `model.save()` (weak)

Comment: I am still new to Django. I am using admin only in the moment. So I  tried it with model.save() before, but it was not updating correctly when using save & continue. Thats why I tried to solve it with signals.